# Mobile Data synchronization

Tags: android, ios, mobile, synchronization

I am currently starting to develop a mobile application (iOS and Android) for an existing web platform. This web platform has a REST API and the client application will use that for communicating. The thing is that the mobile application can make changes to the API, and I must have offline support. This will have synchronisation issues:

1. Clients can change the same data offline and then it can create problems when sync that info with the server
2. The web client can change the information as well and the the mobile client is offline and don't see that changes, and my as well change that old content
3. Having the mobile application to store the latest data offline so that the user may work. And the when it comes online it should address changes and send the changes to the server

Are there any theoric things I may read or see algorithms that can be used for this? I mean this is very usual on mobile apps development and I don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: check this http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/05/simple-offline-data-synchronization-for-mobile-web-and-phonegap-applications/

Comment: A warning would be appropriate: 1. An implementation for a full feature fledged synchronization technology will be *über extraordinary difficult*. 2. According to your description, you will very likely require a "full fledged solution". There are only a *few* companies who managed to provide a reliable commercial solution! (see Riak, at basho.com)  It's even not that easy to analyze the whole problem area, as the existence of the many "Simple Data Synchronization Solution for Mobile" do prove.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I blogged about syncing ([sync algorithm for exchanging data in the “Client – Server” model via REST API](http://havrl.blogspot.ie/2013/08/synchronization-algorithm-for.html)). The algorithm I mentioned in the post is used for building sync functionality to support offline clients. It might help you to get some ideas with building the sync logic for your specific requirements.

**Note:** the reason I simply provide the link to the mentioned algorithm instead of explaining it here is that the post includes many valuable comments which compliment the article.

Comment: above link is broken.

Comment: @Shivaraj Patil - the provided link should work. This is a blogger service hosted by Google.

Comment: I double checked it says "No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you can follow below approach.

For example, you are making changes via web client. At that time your mobile is offline. That changes is saved on server. Now, you made changes in mobile also during offline.
Here is the tricky part need to do - When your mobile come online, first check that there is any changes done via web client? if yes, then ask user that "do you want to overwrite it with your last changes?" like this kind of message or whatever you want to display to alert the user that changes are conflicting.

If yes selected, then go ahead and upload changes done by mobile.

Hope, this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: To identify changes are done or not, you can add flag variable on server. :)

Comment: What if data is synced with multiple devices? this doesn't work. This is not the correct way to implement sync. There are 100's scenarios and  conflicts.

Comment: @ShivarajPatil yes you are correct. it will be problem if supports same login in multiple device at time and those devices are offline.